# Is there a difference between extremely slow growing functions and constants with respect to computable functions?

Tags: complexity-theory, polynomial-time, busy-beaver

So let's say we have the function $f(n)$ that gives $k$ such that $k$ is the smallest number that gives a busy beaver function $B$ value from input $k$ that is greater than $n$. Or more succinctly the smallest $k$ with $B(k) > n$. Can there be computable functions that are not in time complexity class $O(n^c)$ for some constant $c$ but that are in $O(n^{f(n)})$. And by extension, is it true that $P = O(n^{f(n)})$?

Comment: Busy Beaver can't be computed, and thus also $f$ cannot be computed (think of a way knowing $f$ to compute BB). I don't understand how this has to do anything with the rest of the question though. And no, if $f$ is constant then $O(n^{f(n)})$ is like $O(n^c)$, which does **not** contain all $P$

Comment: @nirshahar I think I wasn't clear enough, I didn't mean $f$ would be constant. I also did not mean to assert that $f$ is computable. I meant to say that given such slow growing $f$, then complexity class $O(n^{f(n)})$ must contain all functions $O(n^c)$ for constant $c$, since $f$ grows and $c$ doesn't. I was just wondering if such a complexity class for computable functions contains anything other than polynomial-time functions?

Comment: If $f$ grows fast enough (e.g, at least $\omega(\log(n))$), then yea - by the time hierarchy theorem

Comment: @nirshahar Yes, I think I've made it a little more clear, but I specifically meant to ask about the case where $f$ grows slower than any computable function that is not a constant.

Comment: Then $f$ must be constant, otherwise it would need to grow slower than $\log(f(n))$, which is clearly much slower-growing than $f(n)$ itself

Comment: But as you said yourself $f$ is not computable so it does not have to grow slower than its logarithm to grow slower than all computable functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127977/discussion-between-nir-shahar-and-askeroni).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of $f$ is
$$
f(n) > k \Longleftrightarrow B(k) \leq n.
$$
Now suppose that $M$ is a Turing machine that runs in time $C n^{f(n)}$ but not in polynomial time. Since $M$ does not run in polynomial time, for every $k$ we can find $n$ such that its running time for some input of length $n$ is more than $C n^k$; this can be done effectively, by going over all strings. Having found such $n$, we can conclude that $Cn^k < Cn^{f(n)}$ and so $f(n) > k$, implying that $B(k) \leq n$. Since we can compute such $n$ for every $k$, this allows us solve the halting problem, showing that no such machine $M$ can exist.

As for your second question, if $g(n) \to \infty$ then every polytime machine trivially runs in time $O(n^{g(n)})$. Indeed, if the machine runs in time $Cn^C$ then since $g(n) \to \infty$, we have $g(n) \geq C$ for large $n$, and so $Cn^C = O(n^{g(n)})$. This shows that every language in $\mathsf{P}$ also lies in $\mathsf{TIME}(O(n^{f(n)})) = \bigcup_{C \in \mathbb{N}} \mathsf{TIME}(Cn^{f(n)})$ (often we use $\mathsf{TIME}(n^{f(n)})$ to denote this class). As we have seen above, the converse also holds, and so $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{TIME}(O(n^{f(n)}))$.

Comment: I think this answered my question, so this is just a very weird way one could define the class P...